# R: Merge data.table by two nearest variables

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Edit: Code works just fine, was me that was the problem...

I want to merge several `data.tables` into one. There are three `columns` in each   table, two coordinates `x`, `y`, and a Value assigned to the coordinates. However, the coordinates of the `data.tables` differ slightly so I want to merge the nearest coordinates so I get

```
x y Value_1 Value_2 ... Value_i
```

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435126/merge-data-table-by-two-nearest-variables)  which seems to solve the problem. This solution was offered:

```
#Directly taken from the above mentioned thread:
func = function(u,v){
vec = with(DT2, (u-x)^2 + (v-y)^2)
DT2[which.min(vec),]$Q
}

transform(DT1, Q=apply(DT1, 1, function(u) func(u[1], u[2])))
```

which seemed to solve the problem.

However, if I use the following data:

```
#create data
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(X = runif(10000), Y = runif(10000), Value = runif(10000, min=5, max=10))
dt2 = data.table(X = runif(10000), Y = runif(10000), Value = runif(10000, min=5, max=10))

#Round data
dt1 = round(dt1, 3)
dt2 = round(dt2, 3)

setkey(dt1, "X","Y")

#Function from solution
func = function(u,v){
vec = with(dt2, (u-X)^2 + (v-Y)^2)
dt2[which.min(vec),]$Value_1
}

test = transform(dt1, Value=apply(dt1, 1, function(u) func(u[1], u[2])))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in data.table(list(X = c(0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001,: 
  column or argument 2 is NULL
```

this error message is also appearing when I use my "real" data which is quite similar to the created data above.

I am fairly new and have read quite bit about `data.table` but haven't found a way that works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Q` column in df2, which makes the result to be null for

```
  dt2[which.min(vec),]$Q
```

In `func` definition.

Comment: Oh dear... that was quite obvious, wasn't it! Thanks for pointing that out :-) Works now that I changed it to...